# Keras Error: An operation has `None` for gradient

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Lets assume, that you want to build a `GAN` in `keras`. The generator transforms an image from `domain A to domain B`. Normally the image B is now passed into a `discriminator`, to get a feedback for the `generator` for example like : (yeah your generated image B (lets call it B`) is nearly as good as the real B).

Lets assume that we want to distinguish `spartial information` because domain A and B are just too different there, and the discriminator can easy find patterns in this spartial domain. So he should just use Histogramm data (`HSV`, or texture information like `LBP`) to differ between B and B´.

The problem now is, that you have to use `custom-keras-layers` to transform the B´ images from `RGB to HSV`, and extract texture like LBP, before passing the images into the discriminator. This custom layer has no weigths obviously because its basicly only counting and reshaping (besides the HSV-transformation).

But Keras has its problems with layers without weigths, after using the generator. Somehow the graph cannot be build correctly, and some gradients cant be found. Any ideas why, and how i could fix this error ?

**Custom layer**

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer

class Identity_Loss(Layer):

    def call(self, x):

        assert isinstance(x, list)
        input_1,input_2=x

        # Transform BGR to RGB and than to HSV
        channels = tf.unstack (input_1, axis=-1)
        RGB    = tf.stack   ([channels[2], channels[1], channels[0]], axis=-1)
        RGB=tf.cast(tf.multiply(tf.truediv(tf.add(RGB,1.0),2.0),255.0),dtype=tf.int32)
        RGB=tf.cast(RGB,dtype=tf.float32)
        HSV=tf.image.rgb_to_hsv(RGB,name=None)

############################################################
        SV=HSV[:,:,:,1:]
 ############################################################

# make mask binary and multiply with image
        y=tf.math.greater(input_2, 0)
        y=tf.cast(y, tf.float32, name=None)
        HSV_mask = tf.math.multiply(HSV, y)
######## Count color occurences ###########################
        shape=tf.shape(HSV_mask)
        length=shape[1]*shape[2]

# transform
        Hue=HSV_mask[:,:,:,:1]
        Hue=tf.cast(tf.multiply(Hue,255.0),dtype=tf.int32)
        Hue2 = tf.reshape(Hue, [length])

# prevent that the shape changes
        filler=tf.range(0,length, 1,dtype=tf.int32) 
        filler = tf.reshape(filler, [length])
        Hue3 = tf.stack([Hue2,filler],axis=-1)
        Hue3 = tf.reshape(Hue3, [2*length])

## Count Hue       
        y1, idx1, count1 = tf.unique_with_counts(Hue3)

        maximum=tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_max(count1[1:257]),dtype=tf.int32)
        diff=tf.reshape(count1[1:257],(16,16))
        diff=tf.expand_dims(diff, axis=-1)
        diff=tf.expand_dims(diff, axis=0)
        diff=tf.truediv(diff,maximum)
        diff=tf.cast(diff,dtype=tf.float32)

        return [SV,HSV_mask,diff]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        return [[input_shape[0],None,None,2],[input_shape[0],None,None,3],[input_shape[0],None,None,1]]
```

Wrapping the layer into a structure like that:

```
def Combined_model():

  input_A = Input(shape=[None,None,3])
  input_B = Input(shape=[None,None,1])

  fake_A=generator(input_A)

  SV,HSV_mask,diff=custom_layer([fake_A,input_B])

  dis1= discriminator_1(diff)

  model = Model([input_A,input_B],[dis1])
  model.summary()

  return model

Combined= Combined_model()
dis1=Combined.predict([x,grtr])

# just for testing
generator.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
generator.train_on_batch([x,grtr],[dis1])
```

**Calling the combination**, leads to this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-39-6930bbb3352b> in <module>()
     32 generator.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
     33 
---> 34 generator.train_on_batch([x,grtr],[gt_iso,fake_HIS,SV])

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1511         else:
   1512             ins = x + y + sample_weights
-> 1513         self._make_train_function()
   1514         outputs = self.train_function(ins)
   1515 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _make_train_function(self)
    314                     training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
    315                         params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
--> 316                         loss=self.total_loss)
    317                 updates = self.updates + training_updates
    318 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py in get_updates(self, loss, params)
    502     @K.symbolic
    503     def get_updates(self, loss, params):
--> 504         grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    505         self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]
    506 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py in get_gradients(self, loss, params)
     91         grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
     92         if any(x is None for x in grads):
---> 93             raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '
     94                              'Please make sure that all of your ops have a '
     95                              'gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). '

ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Somehow keras tries to calculate gradients, on layers without weigths. Obviously it fails, because there are None. I basicly tried to rebuild the structure of the keras custom "[Antirectifier](https://keras.io/examples/antirectifier/)" example, without `build` method and the use of `super` to not initialize any weigths.

Is there a possibility to skip the backpropagation, over the custom layer, instantly to the generator?